# Android URL for facebook sharing

Tags: android, facebook

I noticed there are many urls like: tel:0982222222 (in Android, would create an intent which would route to a make-call utility) sms:0982222222 (the same but prepares an SMS. also accepts a body with the message to prepare the application).

I want to share an url in facebook, from another app. The fact is that the app is made in PhoneGap so I can't use any native solutions (like manually creating an intent) since the button (a custom button intended to Share the current url) is displayed in the standard phonegap WebView, so i'd need a link-button like:

```
<a href="xxx:yyy" class="my-custom-button-class">Share</a>
```

xxx:yyy would be like tel:0982222222 if i wanted to link to a phonecall app.

**Q**: How would I compose such url if I wanted to share the url [http://bar.foo.com/path/point?param1=a&param2=2&param3=[]](http://bar.foo.com/path/point?param1=a&param2=2&param3=%5b%5d) (or the exact same case for https)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using phonegap, I would suggest solving this problem with Facebook javascript SDK.

You would need to add the sdk to your html page and then add this code which would draw a button to share on facebook.

`<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://bar.foo.com/path/point?    param1=a&param2=2&param3=[]" data-type="button_count"></div>`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Comment: Is there a way to do it using an application link/intent? By using what you tell I'd break the site style (can't use the facebook-style for button).

Comment: you could try this facebook plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin. I am unaware of any other solution that would react well to unavailability of the Facebook on a user's phone